# How to do not insert the message content in the Message Inbox when use MFMessageComposeViewController control

Tags: iphone, ios, messageui

In my app use the MFMessageComposeViewController control to send SMS message.
The message content will be inserted to Message Inbox of iPhone.

How to do not insert the message content in the Message Inbox when use this control?
Because my message content has been encrypted. I don't want user can see them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this when use the MFMessageComposeViewController.
You should have a look at using your own SMS gateway provider if you want to do this.